When hitting enter in iterm2, it sometimes opens a menu bar instead of running the command
I recently switched from Hyper terminal to iterm2.
iterm2 shows really weird behaviour where on every 10th or so enter, it opens a menu bar dropdown instead of executing the command. Does anyone know why this happens? How can I disable it? It's very annoying and I couldn't find any reports of this when googling. I don't even know how to start googling for it.
This is what pops up when I hit enter (I've tried to screencast it, but it's not super reproducible, so I'd have to run the screencast for minutes, but screenshot works):

